# C# console app generating graphs as bitmap

Tags: c#, charts, bitmap

I am looking for a method to generate graphs from a within a console app (or NT service) and export to a bitmap.
This is a backend process so the graph never gets displayed. just saved to file.
Needs to be completely threadsafe as my console will be doing this multiple times in parallel.

3rd party component is fine, but free is better :D

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Charting components - free:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

---

Update 2023-03-07:
The above link no longer works. There is a [Web Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170606173450/https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61) copy dated 2016-06-06, that page suggests that the file was last updated in 2014.

Comment: Sorry but can you provide a new link?
Its now broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with GDI+ you can draw whatever you want on an in-memory bitmap and save it to a file.  As long as you don't reference the same file or pass the same source data references in multiple threads, you should be fine.  Here's a short example of how to procedurally generate a bitmap that you can wrap in a console app, windows service, web service, etc.:

```
    Image bmp = new Bitmap(intWidth, intHeight);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, intWidth, intHeight);

    g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, g.VisibleClipBounds);

    bmp.Save(strFileNameWithPath);
```

As far as generating graphs are concerned, it's going to be highly dependent on how good your math skills are, how your source data is structured, and what kind of graphs you're wanting to make.  There are definitely libraries out there that do this already (Telerik comes to mind), but I'm a "roll your own" kind of coder. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the excel interop assembly.  Works great for charts and is very easy to use.  There is also a lot of customization and modifications you can make to the charts.

Simple tutorial:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel-chart

This is the assembly file that you should need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In general we prefer you to try something and ask the question when you run into trouble.

That said, assuming that you want to render the charts yourself (i.e. not using a pre-made charting package), I'd have a look at the [Bitmap class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) and the Graphics class, specifically [Graphics.FromImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage).  The bitmap is an in-memory representation of an image, and the Graphics class provides you with methods to draw to it.